# left and right rotations AVL tree in c

Tags: c, rotation, avl-tree

I've implemented a code for left and right rotations in AVL trees in c but apparently it looks like it doesn't work like at the end of some series of insertion operations I only get the first and the last keys inserted in my tree like if I insert all the even numbers between 0-999 like:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10...,998.
```

I only get the first key and the last key in the tree, so my tree looks:

```
0
  \ 
   988
```

i just want to verify if the code i have written is right or not and thanks.

```
struct Node{
  NodePtr left, right, parent;
  int key, height;
  int MaxInClassTree;
  int tree_size;
};

//left rotation
NodePtr real_left_rotate(NodePtr node)
{
   NodePtr y;
   y=node->right;
   node->right=y->left;
   y->left=node;
   node->parent=y;
   y->parent=node->parent;
   y->left->parent=y;
   y->right->parent=y;
   node->height=height(node);
   y->height=height(y);
   return y;
}

//the right rotation
NodePtr real_right_rotate(NodePtr node)
{
  NodePtr y;
  y=node->left;
  node->left=y->right;
  y->right=node;
  node->parent=y;
  y->parent=node->parent;
  y->left->parent=y;
  y->right->parent=y;
  node->height=height(node);
  y->height=height(y);
  return(y);  
}

 //after checking in the insertion that the node is not balanced we fix balance by this function
 void fix_balance( NodePtr node )
{
 int balance1=balance(node);
 if(node->left && balance1>1 && height(node->left->right) < height(node->left->left))
   node=real_right_rotate(node);

if(node->right && balance1 < -1 && height(node->right->right) > height(node->right->left))
   node=real_left_rotate(node);

if(node->left && balance1 > 1 && height(node->left->right) > height(node->left->left))
  {
      node->left=real_left_rotate(node->left);
      node=real_right_rotate(node);
  }

   if(node->right && balance1 < -1 && height(node->right->right)< height(node- >right->left))
   {
      node->right=right_rotate(node->right);
      node=left_rotate(node);
  }
      return;
}

 //returns the height of a node(suppose the height of a leaf is 0 and null is -1)
 int height( NodePtr node )
{
if(node==NULL)
    return -1;
return node->height;
}


//returns 1 if the node is balanced(|balance|<=1) otherwise 0
int is_balanced(NodePtr node)
{
int h;
if(node==NULL)
    return 1;
h=height(node->left) - height(node->right);
if(h<-1 || h>1)
    return 0;
return 1;
}

 //returns the balance of a node(height of the left sub-tree - height of right sub-tree)
 int balance( NodePtr node )
{
if(node==NULL)
    return 0;
return (height(node->left) - height(node->right));
 }

  NodePtr insert_AVL(NodePtr root,int x)
 {
if(root==NULL)
{
    root=get_new_node(x,REGULAR_KEY);
    root->MaxInClassTree=root->key;
    return root;
}

if(root->key==x)
    return root;

if(root->key > x )
{
   root->left=insert_AVL(root->left,x);
    root->left->parent=root;
}

if(root->key < x)
{
    root->right=insert_AVL(root->right,x);
    root->right->parent=root;
}
root->height=(MAX(height(root->left),height(root->right))+1);
if(!is_balanced(root))
    fix_balance(res_tree,root,x);
  if(root->right)
  root->MaxInClassTree=root->right->MaxInClassTree;
  else
    root->MaxInClassTree=root->key;

    if(root->left && root->right)
    root->tree_size=root->left->tree_size+root->right->tree_size+1;
else
{
    if(root->left)
        root->tree_size=root->left->tree_size+1;
    if(root->right)
        root->tree_size=root->right->tree_size+1;
}
return root;

}
```

Comment: Please fix the indention of your code, it's hard to read

Comment: Also, the code doesn't come close to compiling (and some of the errors indicate that's not your real code). See [mcve] in the [help].

Comment: @Mulliganaceous in the example i dont get to a situation that i have to do a left-right rotation

Comment: all im asking for is to check if my implementing for the left and the right rotations are right or wrong just to make sure i wrote it in the right way and to verify that i didnt lose any pointers in this function because it looks like i've lost and if u would like to help it would be great if someone writes for me a classic left rotation or right rotation for avl tree without the parent thing i would be so happy and thankful and thanks guys